# Evaluate function at $\infty$ in $\mathbb{C}^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

What is the definition of $f(\infty)$ in $\mathbb{C}^\infty$? Supposing that I have a function like $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, how I can evaluate the function at $z=\infty$? Because $f(\infty) = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ which is undefined.

My questions:

1. Can be $f(\infty)$ determined by evaluating f($\frac{1}{z}$) in $z=0$, so $f(\frac{1}{z}) = \frac{a+bz}{c+dz}=g(z)$ and $g(0)=\frac{a}{c} \implies f(\infty) = \frac{a}{c}$ ?

2. If $f$ is continuous at infinity ($\iff f(\frac{1}{z})$ is continuous at $0$) we have that $f(\infty) = f(\lim_{z \to \infty} z) = \lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) ?$
3. If $f(\frac{1}{z})$ is not defined (so 1. don't work) and $f$ is not continuous at $\infty$ (so 2 don't work) how I calculate $f(\infty)$. What's the general definition? I searched many textbooks and don't appear a definition for this. They just use $f(\infty)$.

Comment: Without other context, you would have to define $f$ at $\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat and how I define it? And can you please tell me if statements 1 and 2 are ok?

Comment: For a linear fractional transformation you can write $f(z)=\frac{a+b/z}{c+d/z}$.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist but my methods are good or not? Nobody said that...

Comment: Why did you write $f(\infty) = \infty$ in 1.? I think 2. is the definition that is generally used. If $f$ is not continuous at $\infty$ (say take [$\exp z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779740/essential-singularity-at-infinity-of-exponential-function)), I don't think $f(\infty)$ could have any kind of a useful definition.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist sorry. It was a typo at 1. Now it's ok? Can be 1 used?

Comment: Yes, I think it's fine. In my previous comment I had better written "if $f$ **does not have a limit** at $\infty$". Then, if it **has** a limit, you can define $f(\infty)$ so that $f$ becomes continuous at $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no way to take an arbitrary function defined on $\mathbb{C}$ and determine a unique extension to $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$. There are infinitely many functions which are identical on $\mathbb{C}$ but different at $\infty$, because with no further restrictions the value may be arbitrary.

For your statement (2), the sentence "$f$ is continuous at $\infty$" is meaningless until $f$ has been given a value at $\infty$. However, the formula "$f(z) \to w$ as $z \to \infty$" can be stated and evaluated whether or not $f$ is defined at $\infty$. The usual definition is something like:

\begin{aligned}
\forall \varepsilon > 0\, \exists \rho\,\, \forall z\,\, |z| > \rho &\implies |f(z)-w| < \varepsilon \quad &(w \in \mathbb{C})&\\
\forall R > 0\,\, \exists \rho \,\,\forall z \,\,|z| > \rho &\implies |f(z)| > R \quad &(w = \infty)&
\end{aligned}

It is a good exercise to show that (1) is equivalent to the formula "$f(1/z) \to w$ as $z \to 0$" and (2) is equivalent to "$1/f(1/z) \to 0$ as $z \to 0$", where those limits are defined completely internally to $\mathbb{C}$ (so no mention of $\infty$ at all). In fact, by putting absolute value signs in the right places, these can be reduced to just limits over $\mathbb{R}$, which you must surely be familiar with.

**If** the limit $L = \lim_{z \to \infty}f(z)$ exists in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$, then the function $\hat{f}$ which agrees with $f$ on $\mathbb{C}$ and is defined to $\hat{f}(\infty) = L$, will be continuous on $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$, and $\hat{f}$ is the unique such extension of $f$. This can be proved if you define the right topology on $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ (but for the "right" topology it is a bit tautological).

Moreover, if $f$ is given by a "nice" formula, so that it is obviously holomorphic on a neighbourhood of 0, then the function $g(z) = f(1/z)$ is automatically holomorphic on a punctured neighbourhood of 0. If $g$ is additionally bounded on a neighbourhood of 0, then [it is a theorem (Riemann's theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) that $g$ has a unique holomorphic extension to a neighbourhood of 0 (and $f(\infty)$ should be defined as $\lim_{z \to 0} g(z)$).

In fact, if a function $g$ is holomorphic on a punctured neighbourhood of $a \in \mathbb{C}$, then $a$ is called a *singularity* of $g$ and there are only three possibilities for the behaviour:

1. $g$ is bounded on the neighbourhood (the case above), in which case we say $a$ is a *removable singularity*. Basically $g$ doesn't "really" have a singularity, it was just defined badly.
2. $z^k g(z)$ is bounded on a punctured neighbourhood of 0 for some $k>0$. Then $a$ is called a *pole of order $k$*.
3. In all other cases, $a$ is called an *essential singularity*.

In case 2, we can prove that taking $g(0) = \infty$ produces a continuous function on $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ - in fact, if you define what it means to be differentiable on $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$, then this extension of $g$ has that property (such a function is called *meromorphic*).

In case 3, we can actually prove that the limit never exists. There is a famous theorem ([Picard's Great Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_Theorem)) which states that when $a$ is an essential singularity of $g$, then it maps every punctured neighbourhood to a dense set in $\mathbb{C}$. In fact, it says much more - but the point is that in this case
the limit cannot exist (because the limit definition says that $g$ *avoids* all large balls if the neighbourhood is sufficiently small).

Functions that are merely continuous on $\mathbb{C}$ and bounded need not have any of these nice classifications. Being holomorphic is really an extremely strong property.